# Refreshing User Form Textbox with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm that has a textbox that is populated from the `=Now()` function. However the data I am tracking runs on a 3 shift schedule, so "3rd shift" will technically be entering their data on next day. I have adjusted for this using an if statement, but my problem is getting my textbox to update on the change of a combo box that allows you to select what shift you're entering for. I tried the DoEvents function at the suggestion from another helpsite, but it did not work. Thanks in advance!

`Private Sub date_txtb_Change()
 If shift_cbox.Text = "Shift 1" Then
    date_txtb.Text = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YY") 'Current Date
    DoEvents`

```
ElseIf shift_cbox.Text = "Shift 2" Then
date_txtb.Text = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YY") 'Current Date
DoEvents

ElseIf shift_cbox.Text = "Shift 3" Then
date_txtb.Text = Format(Now() - 1, "MM/DD/YY") 'Current Date -1
DoEvents

Else
'do nothing'

End If
```

`End Sub`.

Comment: have you tried any of the solution below ? any feedback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong object. Instead of `Private Sub date_txtb_Change()` you should use `Private Sub shift_cbox_Change()`.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! Still new to VBA so I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter your code on the `Change` event of your Combo-Box, also you can use `Select Case` to have a clearer and shorter code, which will also allow you more versatility to add more scenarios in the future (if you needed to).

```
Private Sub shift_cbox_Change()

Select Case shift_cbox.Value
    Case "Shift 1", "Shift 2"
        date_txtb.Text = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YY") 'Current Date

    Case "Shift 3"
        date_txtb.Text = Format(Now() - 1, "MM/DD/YY") 'Current Date -1

    Case Else
        'do nothing , or something for future scenario

End Select

End Sub
```